# Error adding order: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql

Hey guys I would love your help in regards to the code below, I am quite new to php and and sql, and I am trying to blind these values for a order check out process. There are multiple pages that I need to capture the information from....

I have looked over this code for hours and I am unable to find where I am going wrong...
This may be because I am really not sure where I need to be looking to fix this problem. Any help or advice would help so much!

```
function writeOrderToDatabase(){
 // open database connection
 include 'includes/connection.php';

 // store order date in Australian format for printouts etc
 $_SESSION['orderDate'] = date('d-m-Y');

try{
 // create our sql insert orders statement
  $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET orderNbr=: orderNbr,custNbr=:custNbr,orderDate=:orderDate, OrderNetValue=:OrderNetValue,deliverTo = :deliverTo, 
  deliveryAddress1 = :deliveryAddress1, deliveryAddress2 = :deliveryAddress2, deliverySuburb = :deliverySuburb, 
  deliveryState = :deliveryState, deliveryPostCode = :deliveryPostCode, deliverySuburb = :deliverySuburb, deliveryState = :state, deliveryPostCode = :deliveryPostCode, deliveryInstructions = :deliveryInstructions, shippingValue=:shippingValue,  
  paymentType=:paymentType, paymentRef=:paymentRef;";

 // prepare the statement
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$orderNbr = 0;
 // bind the values

 $statement->bindValue(':orderDate', date('Y-m-d'));
 $statement->bindValue(':custNbr', $_SESSION['custNbr']);
 $statement->bindValue(':dispatchDate', $_SESSION['dispatchDate']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryDate', $_SESSION['deliveryDate']);
 $statement->bindValue(':OrderNetValue', $_SESSION['OrderNetValue']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliverTo', $_SESSION['deliverTo']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryAddress1', $_SESSION['deliveryAddress1']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryAddress2', $_SESSION['deliveryAddress2']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliverySuburb', $_SESSION['deliverySuburb']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryState', $_SESSION['deliveryState']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryPostCode', $_SESSION['deliveryPostCode']);
 $statement->bindValue(':deliveryInstructions', $_SESSION['deliveryInstructions']);
 $statement->bindValue(':shippingValue', $_SESSION['shippingValue']);
 $statement->bindValue(':paymentType', $_SESSION['paymentType']);
 $statement->bindValue(':paymentRef', $_SESSION['paymentRef']);
 $statement->bindValue(':sellingPrice', $_SESSION['sellingPrice']);
  $statement->bindValue(':newQtyOnHand', $_SESSION['newQtyOnHand']);
 // execute the statement
 $success = $statement->execute();
 } // end try


 catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Error adding order: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit();
 } // end catch

 // test the result and get order nbr just created or display appropriate message
 if ($success) {
echo $sql = 'SELECT orderNbr FROM orders ORDER BY orderNbr';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['orderNbr'] . "\t";

   }

 }
 else {
 die("<p>Unable to retreive Order Nbr </p>");
 }

 // read cart and insert orderedItem record(s) and update stock on hand in product records
 foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodNbr => $value) {
 // store required details in variables
 $qtyOrdered = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['qtyOrdered'];
 $qtyOnHand = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['qtyOnHand'];
 $sellingPrice = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['price'];

 try {
 // create orderedItem table sql insert statement
  $sql = "INSERT INTO orderedItem SET orderNbr=:custNbr,prodNbr=: prodNbr, qtyOrdered=:qtyOrdered,sellingPrice = :sellingPrice;";
 } // end try

 catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Error adding orderedItem: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit();
 } // end catch

 // test the result and display appropriate message
 if (!$success) {
 die("<p>Unable to execute the orderedItem table insert</p>");
 }

 // create new quantity on hand value for the product record
 $newQtyOnHand = $qtyOnHand - $qtyOrdered;


 try {
 // create product table sql update statement
$sql="UPDATE product SET prodNbr= :prodNbr,prodName= :prodName,price= :price,qtyOnHand= :qtyOnHand,description= :description, photo= :photo,thumbNail= :thumbNail ,suppCode= :suppCode ;";
 } // end try

 catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Error updating product qtyOnHand: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit();
 } // end catch
 // test the result and display appropriate message
 if (!$success) {
 die("<p>Unable to execute the product table update</p>");
 }
 } // end of foreach
 } // end of function
```

Comment: first step: read the error message and understand what it's trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$statement->bindValue(':dispatchDate', $_SESSION['dispatchDate']);
$statement->bindValue(':deliveryDate', $_SESSION['deliveryDate']);
$statement->bindValue(':sellingPrice', $_SESSION['sellingPrice']);
$statement->bindValue(':newQtyOnHand', $_SESSION['newQtyOnHand']);
```

These bind don't exist in the query.

Besides,

```
orderNbr=: orderNbr
```

should be

```
orderNbr = :orderNbr
```

Please note you don't bind it either.
Also, you're having twice the following parameters in the query:

```
deliveryState = :state
deliveryState = :deliveryState
deliveryPostCode = :deliveryPostCode
deliveryPostCode = :deliveryPostCode
```

Comment: you guys are awsome I will be working on this today and will let you know how I go. You have helped out a million!

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad placeholder token first off: `orderNbr=: orderNbr` needs to be `orderNbr=:orderNbr`; Note the whitspace. Secondly, even if that was correct i dont see you binding `:orderNbr` anywhere.

I would think though that the order number should be an autoincrement integer field, and if that is the case you should not include it in your insert.